# BIOS Real Mode Alert NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm, bios

Is it possible to create an alert sound (like '\a' in C) using BIOS interrupts with assembly? 
If so, how can I do it? I have tried to print \a, but that did not work as intended.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29168974/how-to-play-chords-in-asm-8086

Comment: Simply listing your requirements and asking for help is not a good way to ask a question on this site. Please see [Why is "Can someone Help me" not an "actual" question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question). Show us how _you_ tried to solve the problem yourself, then show us _exactly_ what the result was, and tell us why you feel it didn't work.

Comment: Might this not depend on which BIOS you're using? Which machine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
mov ah, 0Eh
mov al, 07h
int 10h
```

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H

Teletype output AH=0Eh
AL = Character

Comment: Actually, if you put your '\a' between "back quotes" ( the characters we use here to set off "code": `\a`), Nasm will recognize it as an "escape sequence" - called 'BEL'... with one 'L'. Probably easier to write it as "7".